# Bibliography numbering style

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, custom-bib

I'm creating a bibliography for a paper submission to The Bulletin of Math Biology.  I've created a custom .bst file with custom-bib, but haven't been able to get the numbering correct.  I'm not sure if I've missed an option in custom-bib, if I need to do something unusual with custom-bib, or if this must be controlled elsewhere.

Here's the current/required versions of the numbering style (everything else is correct, sorry about the poor image quality in the "required")

Current:

[image: Current numbering]
Required:

[image: Required numbering]

How do I go about changing this?

Comment: Do you need this only in the "References" section (with brackets in citations and without in the bibliography)? If so, a `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}\makeatother` in your preamble should work

Comment: @henrique This changes the numbering style to be correct, but still leaves the indent on the second line.  How would I modify your command so the indent does not occur?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Removing the brackets from the item's label in the bibliography

To remove the brackets from the item's label in the bibliography, you just need to redefine `\@biblabel`. It's original definition is

```
% latex.ltx, line 6161:
\def\@biblabel#1{[#1]}
```

So you can change it with `\renewcommand` to print, instead of `[<arg>]`, `<arg>.`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
```

#### Removing the hanging indent in the bibliography

We must redefine `thebibliography` environment, which is a `\list`. To make things easy, I checked the definition of `asparaenum` environment, from the [**`paralist`**](http://texdoc.net/pkg/paralist) package and reproduced the lenghts in the `thebibliography` environment (which we need to redefine). Assuming you're working with `article` class:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\section*{\refname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
    \@openbib@code
    \usecounter{enumiv}%
    \let\p@enumiv\@empty
    \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m
% We redefine the lenghts here
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{.5em}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
    \parsep\parskip
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
    \partopsep\parskip
    \itemindent\parindent
    \advance\itemindent\labelsep
    }
 {\def\@noitemerr
   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist}
\makeatother
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Geddes:2003,
  author = {Geddes, Chris D. and
            Parfenov, Alex and
            Gryczynski, Ignacy and
            Lakowicz, Joseph R.},
  title = {Luminescent Blinking from Silver Nanostructures},
  journal = {The Journal of Physical Chemistry B},
  volume = {107},
  number = {37},
  pages = {9989-9993},
  year = {2003},
}
\end{filecontents}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}
% article.cls, line 570:
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\section*{\refname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
    \@openbib@code
    \usecounter{enumiv}%
    \let\p@enumiv\@empty
    \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m
% We redefine the lenghts here
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\labelsep}{.5em}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
    \parsep\parskip
    \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
    \partopsep\parskip
    \itemindent\parindent
    \advance\itemindent\labelsep
    }
 {\def\@noitemerr
   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\cite{Geddes:2003}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "everything else is correct":

1. Your author list is abbreviated after the first author, while this is not so in the required version. Change your `custom-bib` answer for "MAX AUTHORS BEFORE ET AL" from the default one to at least 4, or change the corresponding `dbj` option from `mct-1` to at least `mct-4`.
2. The required version uses a comma after the author list, the year, and the title, while your style uses a period. Change your `custom-bib` answer to "PUNCTUATION BETWEEN SECTIONS (BLOCKS):" to `c`, or add the corresponding option `blk-com` to the `dbj` file.