# Is there a wiki-style bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, wiki

Browsing the internet for a bibliography style to use, I didn't find one I liked. As an Wikipedian, I want a bibliography similar to the [one used in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Citation_Style_1). See the image below, taken from the COVID-19 article, for reference:

[image]

Ideally, I want it to look and behave just like the real deal. Are there a package or something similar I can use? Or can someone give me some simple instructions on how to make one myself or, if your the absolute best, can create one for me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The sub-items at reference 459 may be a problem, but other than that a three-column numerical bibliography style with linked titles as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534216/when-using-elsarticle-cls-how-to-make-each-bibliography-item-a-clickable-hyperl/534369 for example will come close, combined with for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84991/bibliography-numbering-style for the number format.

Comment: Note: if anybody wants to try to develop my comment above into an answer then feel free to do so, the comment is not ment to "claim" or answer the question.